# "t is undefined" error when making Leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, undefined

My WebConsole is telling me that "t is undefined" when I click my "resetMap" button. Here is the javascript for the resetMap function

```
function resetMap() {

    /* This creates a variable which groups the layers.
    */

    var layerGroup = L.layerGroup([Frog1Layer, Frog2Layer, Frog3Layer, Frog4Layer, Frog5Layer, Frog6Layer, Frog7Layer, Frog8Layer]);


    /* This removes the variable layerGroup from the map.
    */

    map.removeLayer(layerGroup);

    /* This changes the map centre & zoom level to default.
    */

    map.setView(new L.LatLng(0,0), 1);
}
```

Here is the error in the console

```
TypeError: t is undefinedleaflet.js:5:652

u https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js:5

getLayerId https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js:5

addLayer https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js:5

initialize https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js:5

i https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js:5

layerGroup https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js:5

resetMap file:///F:/GIS Assessment 1/MyScript.js:247

onclick file:///F:/GIS Assessment 1/MyHTML.html:1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think that `map.removeLayer` expects only `layer` not `layerGroup`

Comment: You error shows that the problem is down in the `leaflet.js` file. You could get a better idea of the problem by checking in there. You need to follow your stack trace. `resetMap` calls `layerGroup` in `leaflet.js`. Then that calls `i` -> `initialize` -> `addLayer` -> `getLayer` -> finally `u`. Within the call to `u` an attempt to access an undefined member `t` occurs. It could be that one of the items you are passing in to `L.layerGroup` is not defined or assigned properly, but you need to provide more information if you want someone to help further.

Comment: When debugging, please use `leaflet-src.js` instead of `leaflet.js` - it will make your error messages and stack traces easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

The error description should be pretty accurate: one of your layers is undefined.

You could skip creating layer group, though:

```
let layers = [Frog1Layer, Frog2Layer, Frog3Layer, Frog4Layer, Frog5Layer, Frog6Layer, Frog7Layer, Frog8Layer]

for (let layer of layers) {
  if (layer) {
    map.removeLayer(layer)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a gem! Just wondering if you could just quickly explain what you did there? I know let layers = is storing the layers as a variable, and then you use a conditional statement to delete the layers if they are on the map, but what does "for (let layer of layers) {" do exactly? Apologies, I'm v new to javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this generic error today, the cause was an old version of leaflet-markercluster. When you try to download it from the github page, the readme implies that the latest version is the one for leaflet 0.7 but there are many newer versions. You have to click the releases option on the side and pick an appropriate version from there.

I know this is a tangent compared to the actual question here but this error text is next to useless and this question is the best result that comes up for it.

Hopefully this saves someone some time.